# Push to UIViewController from SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, pushviewcontroller, uihostingcontroller

My app is a hybrid of `UIKit` & `SwiftUI`. I have a use case where a user may need to tap on a `Button` from a `SwiftUI.View` but push to a `UIViewController` or another `UIHostingController`.

My project uses `Storyboard`.

I'm using `UINavigationController` & `UITabBarController`.

There are two scenarios I am looking at.

1.) From my initial launch on my home screen, I can tap a button and within its action I have:

```
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: RootView())
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

This works as expected.

2.) I tap on a different tab and it defaults to my `SwiftUI` RootView which is hosted in a custom `UIHostingController` which I use in my `Storyboard`. Here, if I tap on a button to trigger the push, it doesn't push. I just see the `View` I am on update.

I'm also using a custom `UINavigationController`. From my `Storyboard`, the tabs relationship goes to the custom `UINavigationController` & then its root is the appropriate `UIViewController`. In one scenario though it's my custom `UIHostingController` so I can load a `SwiftUI` View initially from the tab selection.

Here is what I have tried doing to handle push to a View Controller from my SwiftUI View:

```
final class AppData: ObservableObject {
    weak var window: UIWindow? // Will be nil in SwiftUI previewers

    init(window: UIWindow? = nil) {
        self.window = window
    }
    
    public func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool = true) {
        let nvc = window?.rootViewController?.children.first?.children.first as? UINavigationController
        nvc?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
}

// This is what is triggered from the Button action.
func optionSelected(option: String) {
    if let optionId = Common.getIDByOption(option: option) {
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: RootView())                
        appData.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

What happens:

- I do see the data change, but it's all on the same View I am already on.
- I need to push to the new `UIHostingController`.

Comment: Could you provide more context? Does this views are controlled  with `UINavigationController` or `NavigationLink`?

Comment: @Błażej I have added more context above. Please let me know if any additional context is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're mixing `UIKit` and `SwiftUI` in a way where `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` are handling the navigation. I advise you to cut `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink`. The reason behind it is simple. `SwiftUI.View` will be recreated on each switch to tab. Hence, you would start from the begining. You could walk around it, but in this situation, easier will be use `UINavigationController`.

Let's assume you're app has two tabs. I would put `SwiftUI.View` in `UIHostingController` and then in `UINavigationController`. In `SwiftUI.View` I would put closure `let onTap: () -> Void` which would be called whenever you need to push next `UIHostingController` or `UIViewController` to `UINavigationController`.

Example

```swift
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

final class MainViewController: UITabBarController {
    let firstTab: UINavigationController = {
        let navigationController = UINavigationController()
        navigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "First", image: nil, tag: 1)
        return navigationController
    }()

    let secondTab: UINavigationController = {
        let navigationController = UINavigationController()
        navigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Second", image: nil, tag: 1)
        return navigationController
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpFirstTab()
        setUpSecondTab()
        viewControllers = [firstTab, secondTab]
    }

    func setUpFirstTab() {
        let firstView = FirstView { number in
            let secondViewHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: SecondView(number: number))
            self.firstTab.pushViewController(secondViewHostingController, animated: true)
        }
        let firstViewHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: firstView)
        firstTab.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "First", image: nil, tag: 1)
        firstTab.viewControllers = [firstViewHostingController]
    }

    func setUpSecondTab() {
        secondTab.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Second", image: nil, tag: 2)
        secondTab.viewControllers = [FirstViewController()]
    }
}

// Views for the first tab
struct FirstView: View {
    let onTap: (Int) -> Void
    @State var number: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Number \(number)", value: $number)
            Button {
                onTap(number)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to the next view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    let number: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("Final view with number \(number)")
    }
}

// Views controllers for the second tab
final class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect, primaryAction: UIAction(title: "show next view controller") { _ in
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(), animated: true)
        })
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

final class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
    }
}
```